# How to make Jenkins ignore "% Conditionals" in the "Coverage Metric Targets" (W column)

Tags: code-coverage, jenkins

The "W" column on the Jenkins dashboard shows stormy for all of my PHP projects due to the contributing line

```
Clover Coverage: Conditionals 0% (0/0)
```

because `PHP_CodeCoverage` doesn't measure conditionals. How can I make Jenkins ignore this measurement for these projects? I have tried setting `<conditionalCoverage>` to `0` and `-1` with no effect (yes, I remembered to reload the configuration).

```
<hudson.plugins.clover.CloverPublisher>
  <cloverReportDir>build/logs</cloverReportDir>
  <cloverReportFileName>clover.xml</cloverReportFileName>
  <healthyTarget>
    <methodCoverage>70</methodCoverage>
    <conditionalCoverage>-1</conditionalCoverage>    <!-- tried 0 too -->
    <statementCoverage>80</statementCoverage>
  </healthyTarget>
  <unhealthyTarget/>
  <failingTarget/>
</hudson.plugins.clover.CloverPublisher>
```

Comment: There are times when reload configuration does not work and you have to restart Jenkins itself. Have you tried that?

Comment: Yes, but that didn't help. Thanks, I eventually figured it out (see answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using -1 *does* work, but you have to rebuild each project. The entries in the summary hover are generated as part of the build and do not change.

Comment: where does one set this? i have the same issue where my build is set to unstable because of the above. thanks

Comment: @charlie_cat - There is a table on each project's configuration page that lets you set the cutoff values for each tool.